# Boot to command line without loading GUI

Tags: boot, command-line, server, kde

I'm running Ubuntu server 19.10
In order to do a few things I installe KDE-Plasma desktop.

But I still want to just boot into TTY command line without loading the GUI etc. I don't want to remove plasma, just not load any of it at boot. Ctrl-Alt-F3 works but still seems that it loads a lot of processes (sleeping but still).

Thank you for any help!